# Read cached Json file as ByteArray with JsonReader

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, jsonreader

I cached a Json file as byte array and want to read it afterwards with the [JsonReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html).

However, the JsonReader takes a [Reader](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Reader.html) as input parameter.

How can I convert me byte array to a Reader and is it worth doing so, or is there a straighter way of caching the InputStream of the Json file and read it afterwards by the JsonReader?

Looking forward to your responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `ByteArrayInputStream` and `InputStreamReader` to get the `Reader` object, e.g.:

```
byte[] array = new byte[50];//json file
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(array));
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !